# Bash command counting files

Tags: regex, bash

I have a thousand album files with  the following filename pattern : AlbumName-Artist-year.ext
I would like to count how many album files are released each year by using  regx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a "report" by using several utilities:

```
 cat albumReport
 #!/bin/bash
 case "${1:-empty}" in
   empty ) echo "usage: ${0##*/} /path/to/Albums" 1>&2 ; exit 1 ;;
 esac
 cd "$1"
 find .  -type f | \
 awk '-F-' '{
     # remove any trailing '.ext' values
     # from last "word ($3) in the line
     sub(/\..*$/,"", $3) 
     # print the year value
     print $3
 }' | sort | uniq -c

# copy/paste everything after the line `cat ...` 
# into a filename of your chosing, or `albumReport`

# after saving above as file, 
# from command line 1x issue this command
chmod +x albumReport
```

Should produce output like

```
 1 1950
77 1966
20 1982
15 1999
```

etc

This assumes your filenames are **all** as you describe, with names like `AlbumName-Artist-year.ext`. If you don't get years, then change the value of $3 in both lines of code.

The `'-F-'` indicates split fields on the `-` char, so your year value should be the third field, hence $3.

IHTH

Comment: I copied it literally and tried it  but I got an error.
Find unknown argument -type:-

Comment: @4everLRG : Opps, corrected above, make that `-type f` (no `-`)!. Sorry, didn't really have a way to test this.

Comment: @4everLRG : Noticed another minor problem and have fixed that. Let me know if you experience other issues, and we'll try to sort it out. Good luck.